# How to use WYSIWYG editor with structured content in Drupal 7?

Tags: entities, wysiwyg

I am wandering what would be the best strategy to combine a WYSIWYG editor and structured content. I want the user to be able to add the following in the body field with a WYSIWYG editor:

- Images
- Links to other nodes
- Links to, for example, YouTube

I also want to be able to have these added images, links etc. as structured content (to put them out in a view, for example.)

Is there a solution for this? I think the best way would be to use entity reference module for that.

Answer (score 2):

For images use [Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) module. For other fields, like YouTube links and entity References, you can create your own module based on Insert's code, or expand it's capabilities and put a patch in Insert's issue queue.